# How can I make an electron.js image app write to and read from a text/xml file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, xml

I'm a web dev student and one of my assignments was to create a desktop application with electron.js.
I have created an image resizing application which works just fine.
The problem I'm having is one of the requirements is to ensure the application writes to and reads from a text or xml file. My application only loads, resizes and saves images in a local folder on desktop, there is no text at all entered by a user. This is what is confusing me as well.

I have searched everywhere for a clue or even some guidance on how to do this specifically with an electron.js image resizing application.
I've tried following along node.js + xml read/write tutorials but its extremely confusing and I don't know how to incorporate this into my application.

Comment: Hello @user16265171, welcome to stackoverflow, which progamming lanugage did you use for the image resizing application that you created? You mean you want to create an interface where users can input text and then create a logic to write/read it to/from a flat file  ?. Please be clear have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi @kplus, thank you for your reply. I used electron.js framework, which utilizes html5, css, javascript and node.js to create the resizing application. In my application, the user needs not input any text, but simply click a button which opens a select file window in order to select the desired image to resize. Once its selected, the user can utilize a slider bar to adjust the size of the image. Once desired size is selected, the user clicks the 'Resize' button. The newly resized image location is shown just below that button.

Comment: @kplus, One of the requirements of my assignment was to ensure the application writes to and reads from a text/xml file. This assessment requirement is what is really confusing me. There really is no need for it, however being an academic assessment requirement I must include it. Really not sure how to do that, as there is no user text input by the user of the application.

Comment: writing/reading from file in Node is pretty straightforward, I will advise, you clarify the need  and how it should work with your supervisor first, then , if you have technical issue you can revert